# opengl on iOS: texture only showed correctly on right upper quarter of the view

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

It's very strange, when I use texture like the bad one below, the texture showed up is terriable, showed only 1/16 size of the view, which should be filled the view with the texture.

but if I set the vertex array like the good one blow,

then the right upper quarter of the view is showed with the texture perfectly!

And I tried more negative vertex coordinate, all failed, buy positive vertex coordinate is OK. I am so confused!

**That means, when I tried to paste the texture to the view, only right upper quarter of the view is OK, other postion (even the full view) can't show, or can't show correctly, WHY?**

**And the program(bad one) works on the simulator, but failed on true device...**

NOTE: squareVertices is the vertex array, coordVertices is the texture coordinate array.

The difference between BAD one and GOOD one is only squareVertices array.

BAD:

**result picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SycVY.png** (sorry I can't post image yet)

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat coordVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};
```

GOOD: (but only the right upper quarter of the view is OK)

**result picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg2Kg.png** (sorry I can't post image yet)

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat coordVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};

// Update attribute values
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTURE, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, coordVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTURE);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, iTexNameY);
glUniform1i(textureUniformY, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, iTexNameU);
glUniform1i(textureUniformU, 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, iTexNameV);
glUniform1i(textureUniformV, 2);

// Draw
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

// glFlush();   
[_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Comment: If you don't share more code, no one will be able to help.

Comment: already improved description, please help to reopen the question.

Comment: Anyone can help? I am going to be driven mad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved this problem after 2 years...

The problem is occurred due to the coordinates of texture and vertex was reversed.

I used to bind the attribute index with the glBindAttribLocation function.

```
#define ATTRIB_VERTEX 0
#define ATTRIB_TEXTURE 1

    glBindAttribLocation(gProgram, ATTRIB_VERTEX, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(gProgram, ATTRIB_TEXTURE, "textureCoordinate");
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work.

So I called function glGetAttribLocation to get the actual index of attribute:

```
int attrib_vertex = glGetAttribLocation(gProgram, "position");
int attrib_texture = glGetAttribLocation(gProgram, "textureCoordinate");
```

And I found that attrib_vertex = 1 and attrib_texture = 0...

So I should set texture array to index 0 and vertex array to index 1.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_vertex, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib_vertex);

glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_texture, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, coordVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib_texture);
```